# req.session.user is undefined in prisma and express

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, prisma, solid-js

I'm making an user session to retrieve the user id or username to display it in my header component after the user logs in. But when I try to get these information in a controller called getUsers which has a get route it returns undefined in the console.

Context:

Its a book search application make in SolidJS (react framework) and I will need the logged user information to make a relationship with a book that the user may have liked (like button).

UserController.js

```
const  { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')


exports.signUpUser = async (req, res) => {
    const {
        id,
        username,
        email,
        password,
    } = req.body

    // Validações
    if(!username){
        return res.status(422).json({ msg: "O seu nome é obrigatório!"})
    }
    if(!email){
        return res.status(422).json({ msg: "O email é obrigatório!"})
    }
    if(!password){
        return res.status(422).json({ msg: "A senha é obrigatória!"})
    }

    //Checar se o usuário existe
    const checkUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            email: email
        }
    })

     if(checkUser){
            return res.json({ error: "Email ja cadastrado!"})
        }

    // Criar senha
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(12)
    const hasspassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)

    try {
        const user = await prisma.user.create({
            data: {
                id,
                username,
                email,
                password: hasspassword,
            } 
        })
    
        res.status(201).json(user).send({status: "ok"})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send({ status: "error" }, error)
    }
}

exports.userLogin = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body

    if(!email){
        return res.status(422).json({ msg: "O email é obrigatório!"})
    }
    if(!password){
        return res.status(422).json({ msg: "A senha é obrigatória!"})
    }

    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            email
        }
    })
    
    
    
    if(!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Usuario não encontrado!"})
    }

    // Checar se as senhas conferem
    const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

    if(!checkPassword){
        return res.status(422).json({ msg: "Senhas inválida!"})
    }

    req.session.user = user;
    console.log(req.session.user)

    try {
        req.session.loggedin = true  
        res.status(200).json({ msg: "Autenticação realizada com sucesso"})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: error.message })
    }
}


exports.getUser = async (req, res) => {  
        const ses = req.session.user 
        try{
            console.log(ses)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I wasn't able to get the user session information in the getUser route, so I decided to use LocalStorage to retrive the user session.

```
function BookInfo(props) {  
    const location = useLocation();
    const bookId = location.state.id
    const user = localStorage.getItem("user")
    const [liked, setLiked] = createSignal(false);
    const handleLike = async () => {
            await axios
            .post("http://localhost:8001/like-book", {
                bookId,
                user
             })
            .then((res) => {
            console.log('Liked', res)
        })
            .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

```
function Header(){

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = createSignal(false);
  const [userId, setUserId] = createSignal('');

  onMount(async () => {
    try {
      //const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8001/user');
      //const dataSession = response.data.ses;
      //console.log(dataSession.user);
      const user = localStorage.getItem("user")
      if(user){
      setUserId(localStorage.getItem("user"))
      setIsLoggedIn(true);    
    }
      else{
        setUserId(localStorage.getItem("user"))
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```